# Repaint slowdown with CSS via Javascript in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit, css-transitions

I've been working on a slideshow script that uses CSS3 transitions, or jQuery's animate when they are unavailable. I've created a custom function to do the slide animations, which does so appropriately. Everything seemed to be working fine, but I've hit a major snag during testing.

For one reason or another, there is an large delay applying the jQuery CSS before and after the transition on large slideshows. For example, the slideshow in the link below is around 9900 pixels wide (container width, most of which is hidden). The container is maneuvered to display the appropriate slide, using CSS3 transition and transform properties. The delay occurs applying the CSS between lines 75 - 82 in the paste below. In particular, applying the 'transition' CSS causes the problem. Add the 'transition' CSS to the stylesheet (rather than applying it with JS), and delay disappears. This isn't really a solution however, because we only want to use CSS3 transitions on specific properties, that can vary (using 'all' in the stylesheet would transition some CSS that we don't want to animate, but change regularly).

Animation function:
http://pastebin.com/9wumQvrP

Slideshow Demo:
http://www.matthewruddy.com/demo/?p=2431

The real problem is with iOS, in which the slideshow (and even the browser sometimes) becomes completely un-usable. I can't pinpoint any errors, and have really exhausted my knowledge of debugging JS. I'm sure it is related to this section of the function after playing around a bit, and disabling CSS3 support within the plugin altogether removes the problem completely.

I'm completely stuck, and really appreciate any help anyone can give.

--- Edit ---

I've tried applying the CSS with native Javascript rather than jQuery's .css function. Same results, no better performance. Also worth noting that this isn't happening at all in Firefox, and seems to only be a problem with Webkit browsers.

Anyone with a solution, would happy to make a donation towards a few beers! I really cannot figure this out!

--- Second Edit ---

Ok, so been debugging and I can see that the slowdown is caused by the browser repaint cycle that is taking a very long time. Is there a better way to handle this that the way it is already doing? Positioning the element absolutely is a known way to reduce repaints, but that isn't really working because the slideshow is responsive. Absolutely positioning the slide images or the slides themselves causes it to collapse.

--- Third Edit ---

A day later, and I've made some progress. Adding 'transition: all 0s ease' to the elements stylesheet CSS has gotten rid of the repaint caused by adding the inline CSS transition property via the custom animation function mentioned in the original post. This causes a significant performance gain, especially when removing the inline CSS transition property when the transition itself has finished.

Good stuff! However, now there is still a slowdown when the inline CSS translate is being removed (that was used to create the hardware accelerated transition effect itself) after the transition, and the left positioning is being applied. When the two happen together, there is a slowdown.

Breaking them up into two separate tasks (the translate removed, then the left position added in a setTimeout with no time specified), again gets rid of the repaints = performance gain, and looks likes problem solved. But sometimes, the CSS transition property isn't get negated fast enough, and the translate removal gets animated. No good, and don't know where to look next to work around it.

Comment: Anyone have any clues on this? I have been at it for so long now, going crazy and can't figure it out. Can't think of a suitable alternative either. As @user1477388 mentioned, the image sizes are (deliberately) huge, and I am starting to wonder how this could effect  the application of adding the inline CSS 'transition' attribute, but can't figure out why. Using jQuery's animate presents no problems with the same images, and reducing the image sizes significantly also helps the situation (but this doesn't suit some use cases which need to be catered for). So stuck, going crazy!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because both posted links are dead, and without them, the question loses much value. It's impossible to improve through editing, as we miss the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think I've managed to figure it out! Just so you know, original post links don't reflect the changes as I've done them on my localhost environment.

Absolutely positioning the slides container has fixed the problem that was occurring with repaint speeds after the transition had taken place (whilst applying CSS properties). Obviously taking them out of the DOM has done the trick, allowing painting to take place much more efficiently.

I originally didn't try this too much because I knew this would add a lot of work to the resizing functionality. I had originally intended to not resize at all in JS, and rely on percentages to do the dirty work. Absolutely positioning the container would cause the slideshow viewport to collapse, rendering the native resizing useless.

However, I was already having problems with sub-pixel rendering in other browsers anyway, so I guess it was time to bite the bullet and rely on fixed pixel values. I then used JS to handle the resizing, using the window resize event. All seems good, however the slideshow was still collapsed due to the positioning. Assigning height values wasn't working correctly, so was at a bit of a loss.

Thankfully, I came across a neat little trick of setting the 'padding-top' of the slideshow viewport to a percentage value, dynamically calculated (desired slideshow height, set in the settings panel for this script, divided by desired width). As padding-top percentages are relative to the width of the element, this did a great job of providing responsive height and correcting the viewport again (no longer looking collapsed).

Here is some info on using padding-top for responsive elements that maintain aspect ratio. Great little trick: http://f6design.com/projects/responsive-aspect-ratio/

All is good now, and things are working well in iOS and webkit browsers. Everything is extremely quick and working as it should. Four days later, and it is finally figured out. Not happy about having to resort to JS for resizing, but I guess it was always going to happen due to percentage inconsistencies between browsers. Lots of decimals = no good!

Thanks to all who tried to point me in the right direction. Definitely got me thinking, and learned a lot of debugging skills that I can use again to make sure transitions are performing well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're loading HUGE images :)

They are too big for the container you have them in, so you scale them down, which is even more resource intensive.

Try resizing them.

Comment: Images are deliberately large for testing. Needs to be able to handle very large images & a lot of them (stress testing, I guess). Script will be a part of a Wordpress plugin that is widely used.

Comment: I suggest writing something on the serverside to shrink the images, then, because I don't think browsers and CPUs can take this stress.

Comment: When CSS3 is disabled and jQuery's animate is used there is no problem at all. Surely that doesn't make sense if it was a resource issue? There is a physical delay before jQuery's .css is getting executed when it contains the 'transition' property. I'm not sure how this could be related. Anyway, I will be writing a server-side resizing script, but if the user loads the page with a larger browser then resizes, the issue will still occur. Importantly, the problem that is occurring is a huge flaw that has to be fixed if there is any hope of providing a fairly bulletproof script.

Comment: If it was a resource issue wouldn't adding the 'transition' CSS property to the stylesheet have no effect on the issue?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what's happening on the technical side.  I just know that the only variable here is that the images are unnecessarily large and should be scaled on the server before they're ever shown to the client.  If you want them to be large to be able to zoom in and see detail, use a separate image with a separate loading function.  Not all your users will have the best internet connections and be able to download large files at lightning fast speeds, especially mobile users.

Comment: Ah, don't worry then, I will be scaling down the images for such cases, especially mobile users. This isn't a finished example, but really the scripting should be able to handle what is currently going on with ease, regardless of image sizes. Adding the transition properties to the stylesheet (rather than applying with jQuery) fixes the issue, but doesn't suite the functions needs. This at least confirms that it can handle images of this size nicely. Seems more a of problem with whatever is going on with the jQuery .css function more than anything. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all congrats for your debugging!
I have been working on the exact same stuff lately and found out that ios devices don't support a large number of images positionned in the same page. It causes crashes and the only solution I found was removing elements instead of just hiding them. The downside is that removing and appending elements causes lags so you have to do it cleverly, when your transitions are done. I thought the best way to go was keep 3 or 5 images in the DOM and replacing the rest with thumbnails of the images, resized to fit the original. When transitions are done, I'd just put the large images back into place...
Hope this helps you a bit on the ios problem at least...

Comment: Really, does using display: none not help? By thumbnails do you mean setting the images as background images? Some interesting information, definitely going to have a look at it when I get this issue sorted out. Thanks!

Comment: Setting display: none on a big image takes almost as much repaint time as removing the node but does not ease memory use so no, it doesn't help much. In my case, the slideshow library detects ios devices and removes unnecessary nodes only in ios context...

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time analysing your code TimeLine with Chrome Dev Tools,  I believe there's some optimization you could do.

As far as I can tell, every single one of your 16 images gets fully repainted every time an animation is requested. This seems quite obvious to me, as there are 16 images in your example, and the Chrome Dev Tools reports 16 long "Paint" executions every time in hit "Next".

In my humble opinion, you should figure out a solution that considers only translating two images: the one you want to hide and the one you want to show. So, consider please, not moving the rest of the images and, instead, leaving them all side-by-side to the shown image.

One more thing, using scaled down images is probably making the paint cycles quite longer. Avoid them whenever you can.

Comment: The effect is one I was looking to go for, as do a lot of similar slideshows. Definitely something I've thought about, and will have a look at. Seems like I may have cracked it now though (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps or not but I noticed you use 3d translation - I would think a simple 2d translation would be enough especially since your third parameter is 0 and might accelerate the issue, also go with fewer images as Armel L. suggested, don't have an iphone to test though... alternatively, this is a solution I used before css3 but should still work move the element containing the images using javascript by modifying left (?and top - the demo only moves left and right though? without the transition effects) and this way you can fine-tune the refresh rate which I think might account for the slowdown... you can go as low as 18 fps without anyone noticing, might even be good enough with just 16fps

Comment: Using translate 3d is a trick used to force hardware acceleration in browsers. Very common and used in nearly all slideshows that utilize css3. It shouldn't/doesn't make a difference overall to what is going on here as the animation itself is pretty good. What is currently wrong is related to repaints that are occurring after transition (through changes of CSS properties) taking a very long time (webkit browsers in particular). Repaints were also happening before the transition, but adding CSS 'transition' and 'translate' properties to the stylesheet seems to have negated their delay :)

Comment: Also I am moving the elements container in the transition itself as you've mentioned. The slide transition is actually just an animated movement of the container itself. When CSS3 is available, translate3d is used, and the position 'left' is added after the CSS3 transition has completed. If CSS3 is not available, the position 'left' itself is actually animated using jQuery's animate. The images themselves aren't being styled at all. This seems to be a great way to get the best of both worlds, but as mentioned some of the repaints are slow when there is a lot of large image.

Comment: I would like to know what exactly you mean by '... but adding CSS 'transition' and 'translate' properties to the stylesheet seems to have negated their delay...' ? Can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this when I was first designing a magazine carousel-style page device.

If you have a series of images within a long "tray", even if they are not within the viewport, they will still take up ram, and you can effectively have five or so before leaks and nastiness begin to happen.

What I found works is "hiding" them ... But make sure they take up the physical space necessary.

What I also found worked was that one could make the 'previous' current and 'next' image are visible and move the tray, 'unhiding' them as they reach those three positions.

In my own system, I skipped the 'tray' holding e images and only had them at -100% width, 100% width and the current one a 0.

I never had much luck with the typical long-tray carousel with large scale background images... Especially with css3 acceleration.